# How to set 2 routes point to the same controller in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web site which has a controller  `MyFirstController`.

That way, I can load the index view by using `https://example.server.com/MyFirst`.

On the other hand, I have another view that renders the link (HREF attribute of HTML A tag) this way:

```
Url.Action("Index", "MyFirst")
```

That URL rendering causes the link to be generated:

```
https://example.server.com/MyFirst
```

So far, so good. Now, I need to have a route something like this

```
https://example.server.com/MySecond
```

That URL should load the same `Index` view of `MyFirst` controller without creating a new controller named `MySecondController`. This is like having a `MyFirst` controller alias named `MySecond`.

In `RouteConfig.cs` file I added this:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "MySecond",
                url: "MySecond/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "MyFirst", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
               );
```

The problem I have with this code is that I have this rendering code in the other view:

```
@if (somecondition)
{
    ... Url.Action("Index", "MyFirst") ...
}
else
{
    ... Url.Action("Index", "MySecond") ...
}
```

I need that if `somecondition` is true, the rendered URL to be `https://example.server.com/MyFirst` and if it is false, the rendered URL to be `https://example.server.com/MySecond`.

The problem I am having is that both are being rendered as `https://example.server.com/MySecond`.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Did you try adding another entry with for maproute with different name like for "MyFirst"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `Url.Action`, use [`Url.Route`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl) as it allows to explictly pass the name of the route to apply for rendering the url.

To render the `/MySecond` url, pass the name of the `MySecond` route.

```
@Url.RouteUrl("MySecond")
```

Do the same to render the `/MyFirst` url, but since it doesn't have an explicit route name, you'll have to pass both the name of the default route and the name of the `MyFirst` controller.

```
@Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { Controller = "MyFirst" })
```

You can omit the name of the `Index` action, as it has been set up as the default one.

Comment: Many thanks... it worked. Just one comment. I needed to use actually `@Url.RouteUrl("MySecond", new {  Action = "Index" })` because this link is inside a partial view which replicates on all pages (this is a navigation menu). When loaded page is a third controller with certain action, for example, `https://example.server.com/MyThird/TheAction`. the actual rendered link for `MySecond` route was `https://example.server.com/MySecond/TheAction`. When using explicit action in `Url.RouteUrl`, the rendered link was the right one: `https://example.server.com/MySecond`.

Answer (score 0):

Custom route should be before default route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "MySecond",                                          
                "MySecond/{action}/{id}",                            
                new { controller = "MyFirst", action = "Index",id = UrlParameter.Optional  }
            );

routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller try using

```
[Route("MyFirst")]
[Route("MySecond")]
public class MyFirstController : Controller
{
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Url.Action use [Url.Route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2). This method has the option to provide the route name and optionally the action and controller.

```
if (somecondition)
{
    @Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { Controller = "MyFirst" }) //Action "Index" will be defaulted so do not need to provide it
}
else
{
    Url.RouteUrl("MySecond");
}
```

You could also create extension methods on UrlHelper so that you don't have "magic strings" littered through out your views:

```
namespace MyWebsite.Helpers
{
    public static class UrlHelperExtension
    {
        public static string MyFirst(this UrlHelper url)
        {
            return url.RouteUrl("Default", new { Controller = "MyFirst" });
        }

        public static string MySecond(this UrlHelper url)
        {
            return url.RouteUrl("MySecond");
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use `@Url.MyFirst()` or `@Url.MySecond()`

Answer (score 0):

You can set 2 route point to the same controller like shown below:

```
[Route("first_route")]
[Route("second_route")]
public class MyController : Controller{

}
```